# MaskedTextBox Inherit Custom EventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms

I have built a Custom `MaskedTextBox`, changing the values of `BeepOnError` and `AsciiOnly`, as well as adding a customer EventHandler for `MaskInputRejected`.
I build the class and when I drop it on my Form, the custom properties I added to the Custom class appear, but the changes to the `BeepOnError` and `AsciiOnly` do not, nor does the custom EventHandler fire.

Can someone point out what I did wrong?  The EventHandler works fine if I manually add it to the form.

Custom class;

```
public partial class BaseMaskedTextBox : MaskedTextBox
{
    public string gsOrigValue { get; set; }
    public string gsReadOnlyMode { get; set; }
    public bool gbIsString { get; set; }
...
    private void BaseMaskedTextBox_MaskInputRejected(Object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Character Position", e.Position);
        messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
        messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Reason Rejected", e.RejectionHint);
        messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
        MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "Input Mask Invalid...");
    }
```

In `InitializeComponent(`):

```
this.BaseMaskedTextBox1.AsciiOnly = <b>true</b>;
this.BaseMaskedTextBox1.BeepOnError = <b>true</b>;
this.BaseMaskedTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.BaseMaskedTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.BaseMaskedTextBox1.Name = "BaseMaskedTextBox1";
this.BaseMaskedTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 21);
this.BaseMaskedTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
this.BaseMaskedTextBox1.MaskInputRejected += new System.Windows.Forms.MaskInputRejectedEventHandler(this.BaseMaskedTextBox_MaskInputRejected);
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this as a custom component and dragged - dropped CustomTextBox on the FORM. It does set it correctly as `true`. I checked in the Designer. Also, add the event handler after you drag and drop. It works. See the code below.

```
public partial class CustomTextBox : MaskedTextBox
{
    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BeepOnError = true;
        this.AsciiOnly = true;
        this.MaskInputRejected += new MaskInputRejectedEventHandler(CustomTextBox_MaskInputRejected);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Alas this event is not virtual in the base MS class like other events. Hence,
    /// we have to mark it as virtual now
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
   public virtual void CustomTextBox_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Character Position", e.Position);
        messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
        messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Reason Rejected", e.RejectionHint);
        messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
        MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "Input Mask Invalid...");
    }
```

}

`// Derive a class like this and override the event where you delegate the request to the base class`

```
 public class MyMaskedBox : CustomTextBox
    {
        public override void CustomTextBox_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.CustomTextBox_MaskInputRejected(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

On the Form, now Drag and Drop `MyMaskedBox` , add a Mask say `Numeric (5-Digits)` & try entering characters. The base class handler i.e. of `CustomTextBox` will be called and you will see the MessageBox added in the base class.

**This will solve your issue and you will achieve the desired functionality now.**

Comment: Thanks Angshuman Agarwal, adding the above fixed the problem with these two properties.  I was setting them through "Design" view.  Putting the above in the Constructor resolved that.  But can you help me figure out why the EventHandler will not fire?

Comment: It works.. Updated the answer. Just add the event handler from the designer after you drag n drop the custom masked text box. I just checked. Just copy paste the customtextbox code and then use it on a form. Add the Rejected event handler after you drag on the form.

Comment: Right, I can get the EventHandler to fire if I manually add it to the form.  But I am trying to get the EventHandler from the BaseClass to fire without having to duplicate the code in the form.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, updated the answer. It gives the desired functionality what you want to achieve.